# Is there a quick way to snap an object's origin to world origin along a specific axis?

Tags: snapping

I know that I can select an object in Object Mode and go to the Properties Shelf (N)>Transform>Location and enter a value of 0 in a specific axis in order to snap the object to world origin in that particular axis, but I would like to know if there is a way to get the same result in the 3D Viewport without resorting to the Properties Shelf.

Does any one know if there is a quicker way to snap an object's origin to the World origin along a specific axis in the 3D Viewport without using the Properties Shelf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to snap the object's origin to the world origin (`0,0,0`) all at once, there's the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (clear location).

If you want to snap it to just one axis at a time, you can do this by:

1. Checking the "Manipulate center points" to transform the origin only (and not the entire object).
2. Changing the pivot point to 3D cursor.
3. Snapping the cursor to the world origin (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
4. Scaling any axis to 0 to snap the object origin to that axis:
   For instance, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> Snaps your object to the X axis.

See animation below for a demonstration of the method:

[image: Method]

Comment: Thanks. Also there is a shortcut for "Manipulate center points" which is Alt+,